# Install Dev App on IPhone - Not in List

Tags: iphone, appcelerator

I have recently provisioned my IPhone to be a development device when I had version 3.1 of the firmware installed.

I was forced to upgrade firmware last night due to 3.2 being the base supported firmware by the framework I am using. I am now running 4.1 of the iOS firmware.

Before I did this the device showed up in XCode as a valid target to run my application aside from the simulator. Now when I open xcode I never see my device in the list. I also look at organizer and it is enabled for development as I am able to look at the console for the device.

Also the provisioning profiles are still there.

I am at a bit of a loss as to what is wrong. I appreciate any ideas people may have as to how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying it shows up in the Organizer, but not in the "Overview" list in Xcode?

Are you perhaps still running the 4.0 SDK, and does it show up with a "yellow light" in the Organizer along with the error message like "this device's firmware is too new for me"? If so, updating to the 4.1 SDK should fix your problem.

Comment: I updated to the 4.1 SDK last night. It does appear in organizer but not in the lop left corner where I can select the target device.

Comment: What does its Summary page in the Organizer say? Does it have the "green light"? Are you sure the project you're using builds for iPhone or iPhone/iPad, and not iPad only? Are you sure the device is enabled for development? Is the project using the correct development provisioning profile, and that the device's UDID is present in that profile?